# Two dice are thrown n times in succession. What is the probability of obtaining double six at least once?

Tags: probability

I know the answer to this question is $1-(35/36)^n$. This is the concept behind it:

> Probability of not getting a double six on a roll of two dice = 1–1/36 = 35/36.
> Therefore the probability of not getting a double six on n rolls =$(35/36)^n$
> Therefore the probability of getting at least a double six on n rolls =$1 - (35/36)^n$

Now I have this dumb doubt: If for one throw of the pair of dice, the probability of getting a double six is $1/36$, then why is it not $1/36^n$ for n throws by the same logic as above?

Comment: $(\frac1{36})^n$ is the probability of getting a double six $n$ consecutive times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of a double six is $\frac{1}{36}=:p$. Now the probability of getting two double sixes in a row is then $p\cdot p= p^2$, $p^n = \frac{1}{36^n}$ is the probability of getting $n$ double sixes in a row, similar to how $\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^n$ is the probability of not getting a double six at all in $n$ consecutive trows.

Comment: yes yes right. Thank you so much for clearing my doubt :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we like to find the probability of the event

$A$: Getting a double six (6, 6) at least once in the total of $n$ throws of the dice.

We calculate $P(A)$ by using the axiom of probability:

$ P(A) = 1 - P(\bar{A})$,

where $\bar{A} = A^c$ is the complementary event.

Here, $\bar{A}$ is characterized by

$\bar{A}$ : None of the $n$ trials results in the double six.

The probability of not getting a double six in one trial = ${35 \over 36}$.

Thus, $P(\bar{A}) = \left( {35 \over 36} \right)^n$.

Hence, using the probability axiom,

$P(A) = 1 - P(\bar{A}) = 1 - \left( {35 \over 36} \right)^n$.

This is the precise answer to the probability question.

What you suggested as $\left( {1 \over 36} \right)^n$ is not the required probability of getting at least one double six in the throw of dice $n$ times.. It is rather the probability of getting a double six in each of the $n$ trials.. This is not asked.. Thanks..

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you